# Change this Oracle SQL Delete to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have an Oracle delete statement I need to port to MySQL.

Here is the statement:

```
DELETE from Student
WHERE DEPTID = '90'
and LOADDT < (Select max(LOADDT) From Student WHERE DEPTID ='90');
```

This does not work in MySQL and errs out,

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'STUDENT' for update in FROM clause
```

How do I port this to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by giving a new alias to your subquery

```
DELETE from Student
WHERE DEPTID = '90'
AND LOADDT < (
SELECT t.LOADDT FROM (
Select max(LOADDT) LOADDT From Student WHERE DEPTID ='90'
) t
);
```

In same table performing delete you can't use the subquery in where clause which belongs to same table so you need to give it a new alias

Comment: Note that MySQL may (will?) execute that subquery for each row returned by the outer query, which can result in slow performance for large sets. In MySQL, a JOIN pattern is usually more efficient. Later versions of MySQL (e.g. 5.6) have made some significant improvements in the optimizer, but I'm not sure there is any improvement for a query of this form. (Avoiding this type of **`NOT IN (subquery)`** pattern has been the normative pattern for MySQL query authors for years.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get an equivalent result in MySQL:

```
DELETE s.*
  FROM (SELECT MAX(m.LOADDT) AS max_loaddt
          FROM Student m
         WHERE m.DEPTID ='90'
       ) r
  JOIN Student s
    ON s.DEPTID = '90'
   AND s.LOADDT < r.max_loaddt
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work and does not need any joins:

```
DELETE FROM Student 
WHERE DEPTID = '90' 
ORDER BY LOADDT DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It won't work it will delete the row that has highest `LOADDT` from op's query it looks like he wants to keep the maximum row and delete the remaining rows that are less from the highest `LOADDT`

Comment: Yes @MKhalidJunaid is right. I want to keep the max row and delete the rest.

Comment: @Ram the value of `LOADDT` can be repeated? If so, do you want to keep all the rows with the highest value of `LOADDT` or only the first one?

Comment: @JaviFernández No the value of LOADDT cannot be repeated. There will one LoadDt per day. Thank you for your help!